# Spring Cloud Stream for Kafka : is it possible to reset offset without restarting the application?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a listener configured with Spring Cloud Stream with Functional Programming model, which consumes messages from a kafka topic.

Is it possible to reset the offset of the consumer group without having to restart the application?

This is a snippet of how the consumer is configured

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myConsumerFunction
        stream:
    default-binder: kafka
    bindings:
      myConsumerFunction-in-0:
        binder: kafka
        destination: my-topic
        content-type: application/json
        group: my-consumer-group
        # Spring Cloud Stream Retry
        consumer:
          max-attempts: 2
          back-off-initial-interval: 1000
          default-retryable: true
          back-off-multiplier: 1
    kafka:
      bindings:
        myConsumerFunction-in-0:
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: true
            ackEachRecord: true
            autoCommitOnError: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a reference to a KafkaConsumer instance of your application, then yes, you can `seek` and `commit` the offsets, effectively doing a "reset".

Otherwise, no, you cannot reset an actively running consumer group externally from `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` script